# Linq MAX in Where clause in Joined table query

Tags: linq

i'm in a situation my mind is blocked en hope someone can help me.

I have two tables. One table with customers of a subsription service and one invoice table. 
these tables are not linked with keys in the database for keeping history of invoices if customers are deleted. This way I have to query the customers table joining the invoiceheader table by another unique contraint (not know by the database). This constraint is using name and address together.

An invoice is send one time a year. In the invoice-header table the date is stored when the invoice is created. In a couple of years constomers can have multiple invoices.

i'm trying to create a linq query but i'm looking the wrong way for a solution I'm afraid.

who can point me the right way?

for now i have a query :

```
var temp = from c in context.customer
           from i in context.invoiceheader
           where c.name + c.address == i.name + i.address
           && i.invoicedate < DateTime.Now.Year
           select c;
```

With this query I get all customers who have receive an invoice last year and stil have subscribed. The trouble is with new customers who never received an invoice.

What to do for customers where in this case they haven't any invoice records.?

summurized: I want to query the last know invoice. If this invoice is older than a year (previous year)or no invoice is sent at al, i wanna retreive a list of customers the should be sent a new invoice.

Comment: is your query returning something ? and you are having trouble where you don't have any value in  i.name or i.address ? and if so what you want to get in that case ?

Comment: the query is working good for existing customers where an invoice is sent in de past. except new customers aren't retreived. So if no invoice exists for a specific customer that customer (invoice = null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that what you want is a left outer join - this way you should be able to get all the customers you need:

```
var customers = from c in context.customer
                join i in context.invoiceheader
                on c.Name + c.Address equals i.Name + i.Address
                into g
                from row in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where row == null ||row.invoicedate < DateTime.Now.Year
                select c;
```